# Showing that a given curve is a circumference

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the curve $\beta(s)=(\frac{4}{5} \cos(s),1-\sin(s), \frac{-3}{5} \cos(s))$. Prove that the trace of $\beta$ is a circumference.

**My approach:**

$(*)$ If there exists a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that for any point $\beta(s)$ the distance between $\beta(s)$ and $p$ is constant, then the trace of $\beta(s)$ is either a circumference or a sphere (is this true?).

I have already proved that $\beta$ is planar, showing that its torsion is constantly zero, but I have failed to prove $(*).$ Any hints or different approaches?

Comment: Try guessing what the center point might be. There are clues in the parameterization of the curve. Failing that, you could find the center from three noncolinear points on the curve.

Comment: What would ${ 1\over 2} (\beta(0)+\beta(\pi))$ correspond to?

Comment: By "a circumference" do you mean specifically of a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \left(\frac{4}{5} \cos s,1-\sin s, \frac{-3}{5} \cos s\right) \tag 1 $$

The set of all points of the form $\big(x,y,(-3/4)x\big)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$ is a plane.

Let $x = \dfrac 4 5 \cos s$ and let $y= 1-\sin s,$ and we see that as $s$ varies, all points of the curve $(1)$ lie within that plane.

As $s$ varies, the average value of $(1)$ is $(0,1,0),$ so if $(1)$ is a circle then that must be the center. Show that the distance from a point of the form $(1)$ to $(0,1,0)$ does not depend on $s.$

Answer (score 1):

Model the circle as $p+ (\cos t) v_1+(\sin t) v_2$, where $v_1 \bot v_2$ and
$\|v_1\|= \|v_2\|$.

Once you compute $p$, it is not hard to guess a suitable $v_1, v_2$ for the
given $\beta$.

Note that the period is $2 \pi$.

> Compute $p={1 \over 2} (\beta(0)+ \beta(\pi))= (0,1,0)$. We can read off $v_1= ({4 \over 4}, 0, - {3 \over 5})$ and $v_2 = (0,-1,0)$.